# Linux cmd to search for a class file among jars irrespective of jar path

Tags: linux, command

I want to search for a particular class file among many jar files without giving the location of each jar file.

Is this possible with a simple command?

I tried this command:

```
grep Hello.class *.jar
```

Which did not return a list of jars containing the class. Then I ran the command:

```
grep Hello.class /full/path/of/jar/file/*.jar
```

Which did return the relevant jar file.  Is there a better way?

Comment: What's the question?  You seem to say you found a method that worked.  It worked because the jar file is a zip-format file, and the directory (containing the names of the files in the jar) is not compressed and thus detectable by grep.  Add the `-l` option to the grep command to only list the matching file names only.

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/search-string-in-multiple-files.html

Comment: `grep Hello.class -r /parent/directory` should do the job

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Where are you jar files? Is there a pattern to find where they are?

#### 1. Are they all in one directory?

For example, `foo/a/a.jar` and `foo/b/b.jar` are all under the folder `foo/`, in this case, you could use `find` with `grep`:

```
find foo/ -name "*.jar" | xargs grep Hello.class
```

Sure, at least you can search them under the root directory `/`, but it will be slow.

As @loganaayahee said, you could also use the command `locate`. `locate` search the files with an index, so it will be faster. But the command should be:

```
locate "*.jar" | xargs grep Hello.class
```

Since you want to search the content of the jar files.

#### 2. Are the paths stored in an environment variable?

Typically, Java will store the paths to find jar files in an environment variable like `CLASS_PATH`, I don't know if this is what you want. But if your variable is just like this:`CLASS_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/bin`, which use a `:` to separate the paths, then you could use this commend to search the class:

```
for P in `echo $CLASS_PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'`; do grep Hello.calss $P/*.jar; done
```

Comment: What is the underlying mechanism for `grep` to find class files in a jar?

Answer (score 40):

Most of the solutions are directly using `grep` command to find the class. However, it would not give you the package name of the class. Also if the jar is compressed, `grep` will not work.

This solution is using `jar` command to list the contents of the file and `grep` the class you are looking for.

It will print out **the class with package name** and also **the jar file name**.

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -print0 |  xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'jar tf {} | grep Hello.class &&  echo {}'
```

You can also search with your package name like below:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -print0 |  xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'jar tf {} | grep com/mypackage/Hello.class &&  echo {}'
```

Answer (score 5):

Just go to the directory which contains jars and insert below command:

```
find *.jar | xargs grep className.class
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Linux, Walkthrough to find a class file among many jars.**

Go to the directory that contains the jars underneath.

```
eric@dev /home/el/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/libs $ ls
blah.txt                             metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
jopt-simple-3.2.jar                  scala-library-2.10.1.jar
kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-sources.jar       zkclient-0.3.jar
kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-sources.jar.asc   zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
```

I'm looking for which jar provides for the Producer class.

Understand how the for loop works:

```
eric@dev /home/el/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/libs $ for i in `seq 1 3`; do
> echo $i
> done
1
2
3
```

Understand why find this works:

```
eric@dev /home/el/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/libs $ find . -name "*.jar"
./slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
./zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
./kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-javadoc.jar
./slf4j-1.7.7/osgi-over-slf4j-1.7.7-sources.jar
```

You can pump all the jars underneath into the for loop:

```
eric@dev /home/el/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/libs $ for i in `find . -name "*.jar"`; do
> echo $i
> done

./slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
./zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
./kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-javadoc.jar
./kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-sources.jar
```

**Now we can operate on each one:**

Do a `jar tf` on every jar and cram it into blah.txt:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.jar"`; do echo $i; jar tf $i; done > blah.txt
```

Inspect blah.txt, it's a list of all the classes in all the jars.  You can search that file for the class you want, then look for the jar that came before it, that's the one you want.

Comment: Very nice. unzip -l also works instead of jar tf. It also automatically prints out the archive name. Some systems might have unzip but not jar.

Comment: This is how SO answers should be formulated!

Answer (score 2):

```
   locate *.jar | grep Hello.class.jar
```

The locate command to search the all path of the particular file
and display full path of the file.

example

```
locate *.jar | grep classic.jar

/opt/ltsp/i386/usr/share/firefox/chrome/classic.jar

/opt/ltsp/i386/usr/share/thunderbird/chrome/classic.jar

/root/.wine/drive_c/windows/gecko/0.1.0/wine_gecko/chrome/classic.jar

/usr/lib/firefox-3.0.14/chrome/classic.jar

/usr/lib/firefox-3.5.2/chrome/classic.jar

/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.1.2/chrome/classic.jar

/usr/share/firefox/chrome/classic.jar

/usr/share/thunderbird/chrome/classic.jar
```

Comment: I think the command should be `locate "*.jar" | xargs grep Hello.class`. I believe the question want to search the content of a jar file.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this small snippet. Might be slower but works every time.

```
for i in 'find . -type f -name "*.jar"'; do
    jar tvf $i | grep "com.foo.bar.MyClass.clss";
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo $i; fi;
done
```

Comment: I assume that you meant to use backticks in that first line?

Comment: Works perfectly with backticks - nice.

Comment: FYI. do not use backticks anymore, this is the old syntax.  Use `$( )` instead.  So it would look like `for i in $(find ...); do ......`

Answer (score 1):

Use deepgrep and deepfind. On debian-based systems you can install them by:

```
sudo apt-get install strigi-utils
```

Both commands search for nested archives as well. In your case the command would look like:

```
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs -I {} deepfind {} | grep Hello.class
```

Answer (score -1):

```
eric@dev /home/el/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/libs $ for i in `find . -name "*.jar"`; do
> echo $i
> done

./slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
./zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
./kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-javadoc.jar
./kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1-sources.jar
```

Comment: FYI. do not use backticks anymore, this is the old syntax.  Use `$( )` instead.  So it would look like `for i in $(find ...); do ......`